# MS-DOS Debugger, move to next memory location

Tags: debugging, assembly, dos, dosbox

I am using DosBox and I have a string read in from the buffer using an interrupt. I know where the first character is stored in memory, how do I increment to the next character?

```
0100 mov ah, 0a
0102 mov dx, 111
0105 int 21
0107 mov dl, [113]      ;first character here
010b mov ah, 02
010d int 21
010f int 20
0111 db 0f
```

The question is how do I increment to the next character in the string? If I input the string "Hello" and then use `inc dl` it simply gives me the letter "I" instead of "e".

Comment: mov 113 into _BX_, and use _BX_ for addressing. You can then increment BX to get to the next memory location.

Comment: Do you know how computer memory works, and what is meaning of that `[113]`? Do you know what registers are? What would happen if you would change `[113]` into `113`? Why `mov dx,111` when calling input? (I'm asking to get idea what has to be in asnwer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick a register to point at the current character.  Once you have this there are instructions to advance your pointer as well as instructions to read the byte the pointer is pointing to.

Since you don't know how many characters will be read by the user input function, and you want this function to work with any input value, you'll need some sort of loop so you only print as many characters as have been read, although if you wanted to make it simple, you could make it only print the first 3 characters regardless of what was typed in.  I'm going to assume you want to print out exactly what was typed by the user.

A good way to tackle this is to use the LOOP instruction which repeats (jumps into) the loop body by the count that has been placed into the CX register.  Since the user input function gives us the character count, all we have to do is read that into the lower portion of the CX register (CL) for loop initialization.  We'll also need a pointer to point to the current character.  Once in the loop body, we'll just read whatever character is at our "current character" pointer and then call the DOS character-print function to output it to the console. Then we can advance the pointer and LOOP until all characters have been done.  Note that each time the LOOP instruction is encountered, CX is decremented until it reaches zero.  Once it is zero, LOOP no longer jumps back into the body and simply advances to the instruction following the LOOP.

NOTE: If you don't output a CRLF after reading the user input, there will be no line feed and the new output will overwrite where the input was read on the console.  Effectively it will look like nothing happened.

Here's your modified sample:

```
0100  MOV     AH,0A
0102  MOV     DX,0123
0105  INT     21            ;input string using buffer at 0123
0107  MOV     DX,0120
010A  MOV     AH,09
010C  INT     21            ;output CRLF sequence first
010E  MOV     SI,0124       ;point SI at byte containing chars read
0111  XOR     CX,CX         ;CX = 0
0113  MOV     CL,[SI]       ;CX = chars_read 
0115  INC     SI            ;mov SI to next char to display
0116  MOV     DL,[SI]       ;DL = character SI is pointing at
0118  MOV     AH,02
011A  INT     21            ;display character
011C  LOOP    0115          ;loop back to INC instruction until no more chars left
011E  INT     20            ;exit
0120  DB      0D            ;CR
0121  DB      0A            ;LF
0122  DB      24            ;"$" DOS string terminator
0123  DB      20            ;buffer start; max characters = 32
0124  DB      00            ;   chars read goes here
0125  DB      00            ;   input chars are read here
```